# jsPDF generating two pdf files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I'm using the code below to create a PDF of an image when the user clicks the "download" button. It's almost working fine but the problem is that it’s generating **two** PDF files instead of one.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#downloadPDF').click(function() {
            var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");

            function getDataUri(url, callback) {
                var image = new Image();

                image.onload = function() {
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
                    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

                    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

                    // Get raw image data
                    callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));

                    // ... or get as Data URI
                    callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
                };

                image.src = url;
            }

            // Usage
            getDataUri('/cover.png', function(dataUri) {
                console.log('RESULT:', dataUri);
                doc.addImage(dataUri, 'png', 0, 0, 210, 297, undefined, 'FAST');
                doc.save('download.pdf')
            });
        })
    })
})(jQuery)
```

I think it’s a loop, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: I just tested this and it keeps generating two pdfs

Comment: Please include enough code (HTML/js) to be able to *reproduce* the issue, see [mcve].  Ideally, include the `script src=` tags to CDNs and the HTML that initiates the code.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be calling `callback` twice, once after the comment `// Get raw image data` and another time after `// ... or get as Data URI`. Remove one of the calls depending which case you want and it should solve the problem.